# Manipulating files through C to make a top 5 leaderboard

Tags: c, file, struct, organization

I'm making a connect 4 game as apart of a project and I want to add extra functionality to it, however I'm struggling.

The code is a function I've written that takes a struct (lb leaderboard) and attempts to read the file for that difficulty of all its inputs into a lb array size of 6 which include the difficulty of the bot, turn count and the name of the player, then organizes it in order of turn count and reprints the top 5 back into the file. 
I set the first element of the old array to the passed by struct of leaderboard data for the organise function bit.

However, when i set it up with template inputs each separated with a new line like such: 
0 7 James
0 13 Jimmy
0 8 Joshua
0 6 Charly
0 9 Jack

It prints this to the file:

0 7 James
0 13 Jimmy
0 8 Joshua
0 6 Charly
(0 9 Jack 1982289408 0 ) same line

The struct looks like this as well{
int turn_count
int diff
char name[20]}

I'm really new to coding so any help is appreciated!

```
lb old[6];
lb temp;

FILE *file;



                if (leaderboard.diff == 0){
                file = fopen("leaderboard0.txt", "r+");}
                else if (leaderboard.diff == 1){
                file = fopen("leaderboard1.txt", "r+");}
                else if (leaderboard.diff == 2){
                file = fopen("leaderboard2.txt", "r+");}

                fseek( file, 1, SEEK_SET );
                old[0] = leaderboard;

                for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++){
                fscanf(file, "%i %i %s", old[i].diff, old[i].turn_count, old[i].name);}

                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
                        for (int j = i + 1; j < 6; j++)
                    if (old[i].turn_count >  old[j].turn_count)
                                        {
                                            temp = old[i];
                                            old[i] = old[j];
                                            old[j] = temp;
                                        }}

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                fprintf(file, "%i %i %s\n", old[i].diff, old[i].turn_count, old[i].name);
                fclose(file);}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow, JJewson

First of all, I **strongly** recommend to you to properly indent your code. One error will be obvious only by that:

```
lb leaderboard = { ... }; /* was missing from your source code */
lb old[6]; /* you should rename this */
lb temp;

FILE *file;

/* somthing that opens a block was missing from your example source */ {
    if (leaderboard.diff == 0) {
        file = fopen("leaderboard0.txt", "r+");
    } else if (leaderboard.diff == 1) {
        file = fopen("leaderboard1.txt", "r+");
    } else if (leaderboard.diff == 2) {
        file = fopen("leaderboard2.txt", "r+");
    }

    fseek( file, 1, SEEK_SET );
    old[0] = leaderboard;

    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        fscanf(file, "%i %i %s", old[i].diff, old[i].turn_count, old[i].name);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 6; j++) {
            if (old[i].turn_count >  old[j].turn_count) {
                temp = old[i];
                old[i] = old[j];
                old[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        fprintf(file, "%i %i %s\n", old[i].diff, old[i].turn_count, old[i].name);
        fclose(file); /* this is the obvious error, it should go below this loop */
    }
    fclose(file); /* here it should be */
}
```

- It would be probably best to rename `leaderboard` to `leader` and after that to rename `old` to `leaderboard`.
- I already mentioned the need to move the `fclose` call outside of the loop. You close the file after your first write.
- I don't understand your first use of `fseek( file, 1, SEEK_SET );`: Why do you skip the first character of the file? (File offsets start at 0 not 1). Also: After a successfull `fopen`, the file pointer always points to the beginning of the file.
- After you read your leaderboard, you should `fclose` the file, and reopen it for (over-)writing. (Better keep a backup, if the leader board is important). So: Open `"r"` for reading, read, close, open `"w"` for writing, write, close.
- You don't do any error checking in your code. You should fix that and inform the user on error and try to handle the error as gracefully as possible. (I.e. do not loose your leaderboard if writing fails.)
- Concerning the added part `1982289408 0`: Make sure, your new leader (struct `leaderboard´) is properly initialized).
- Your algorithm has a slight problem: A new player, who was exactly as good as a previous one, will move that previous one out of the leader board. To fix that, load the file into `old[0..4]` and put new leader into `old[5]` (instead of putting him in `old[0]` and the file content in `old[1..5]`)
- Minor imporovement: The sorting loop: for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) for (int j = i + 1; j < 6; j++)`-> the`for i`loop only needs to run from 0 .. 4, so`for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` would suffice.